# Have to retrieve file from secured website with SQL Server 2000

Tags: https, sql-server-2000, dts, 7zip

I am trying to retrieve a zip file from an https website - so username and password protected with SQL Server 2000. I was thinking that I could use a DTS package or a Job.

There is a wget command - however I am unsure of how to run it from within the constraints. This would be such a huge help being able to do this it is basically having to manipulate the file name every month to reflect part of the month name in the file name as well.

then I will use 7zip to unzip it and walaaa the stored proc is already written just need to get the other two parts complete:)

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will be tricky in SQL Server 2000

If you use SSIS you have more options: is this possible?

For DTS you could look [here](http://www.sqldts.com/302.aspx). This is for FTP but poke around and see what there is

Finally, what vbscript or similar?

Comment: Yes I have thought maybe VBScript is the way to go but I am just getting back into SQL SERVER 2000 for my new job and just adjusting. However I have never done anything like this so I am flying blind lol ;)

Comment: I can use the vbscript also I have wget byt I am unsure of how to get that running 7z any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.